# I have a timed quiz that I need to save username input to local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, addeventlistener

I created a timed quiz that saves the score into the local storage but does not save the user's entered username. I'll include the last HTML doc of the application, the score is saved from the game script file. I figured out that I wouldn't need to edit my game script file as the score does get saved into local storage.

**The HTML code:**

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
    <title>Congratulations</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="end" class="flex-center flex-column">
        <h1 id="finalScore">0</h1>
        <form>
            <input
                    type="text name"
                    name="username"
                    id="username"
                    placeholder="username"/>
            <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="btn"
                    id="submitBtn"
                    onclick>
                Save
            </button>
            <a class="btn" href="game.html">Play Again</a>
            <a class="btn" href="start.html">Go Home</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="assets/end.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript code:** I have commented on what I was planning in my code.

```js
//links username from end html doc

const usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');

//links save socre button from html doc

const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');

//links the final score

const finalScore = document.getElementById('finalScore');

//retrieves the end score from local storage

const mostRecentScore = localStorage.getItem('mostRecentScore');


//pulls most recent score from game script and saves it to end screen

finalScore.innerText = mostRecentScore;

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event)  {
  //keeps entry form being entered into the url
  event.preventDefault();

  var username = document.querySelector("#username").value;
  //turn array entry into a string
  localStorage.setItem('username', username);

});
```

I get an error for the application I am trying to create. A player's username does not get saved into local storage.

Comment: Make sure, that `username` has a value by checking it with `console.log()`. Also, `name` is not a valid type for an input. So, change `type="text name"` to just `type="text"` in the HTML.

Comment: You should remove the `onClick` attribute on the submit button if you don't attach a method to it.

Answer (score 1):

You used `document.getElementById('submit')` to grab the submit button. But in your HTML file, **`id`** of the submit button is `submitBtn` not `submit`. So, you have to use `submitBtn` instead of `submit`.

In JS, the code will be-

```
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
```

Comment: In addition to this, you need to have some validation in place to ensure you have a value, if it's there and not empty.